# what are the paths that resolve the scope of the std library

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

So, I believe I understand the concept of the header method C++. But I read a post which become confusing. If I decide to avoid using directive in my programming I.E (using namespace std), how can I supplement other libraries that I may not be familiar with or where can I find a digital resource to help me resolve scope problems. I know that the "std" part in a std::cout statement resolves the the function from the iostream when I choice to include it. However, I am not getting the convention here. What would the scope parameter for  be in a situation where I wanted to use the it but did not want to use the std namespace and how would this affect un-conventional classes?

Comment: You want to know the path the `std` namespace resolves to? There are many. Many different files contribute to `std::`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Or no files at all. The standard does not mandate files as the implementation for standard headers.

Comment: Can you clarify your question "What would the scope parameter for be in a situation where I wanted to use the it but did not want to use the std namespace and how would this affect un-conventional classes?"

Comment: @Galik 44: What i ment was how would I know when to implement the std:: when i decide to workoutside the std namespace. Is std:: a generic reference to all c++ 11 functions?

Answer (score -1):

Files which contain standart functions declarations - like iostream for example,  are kept in directories depending on what ide you are using. For example, for Visual c++ studio 2008 these files are in [visual studio folder]/VC/include. 
To find all files containing std namespace functions declarations you probably will need to search for all files containing  _STD_BEGIN macro.

Comment: yea, okay that makes since

Comment: This is quite a wild ride for me coming over from actionscript to this stuff. Actionscript 2.0 seemed so organized. I used it for 8 years and got pretty darn good too. But, I have been away from programming heavily for about 5 years and I have been reading a few books on it.(C++ and the OpenGL standard) It seems like a more robust option. I use the a C++ Vishual x86 Native Build Tools Command Prompt and Notepad to program. Is this macro function you are speaking about part of the standard knowledge base a C++ programmer should have. I have not encountered this system but would like to know how

Comment: I am not sure if I have them because I am compiling directly in the command line

Comment: You still have the include directory. I was wrong saying it depends on ide, it more like depends on compiler you are using.

Comment: You still have the include directory. I was wrong saying it depends on ide, it more like depends on compiler you are using. You just have to find out where those header files are.  But generally imho there is hardly any reason to not to want to use "using namespace std".